# Show and hide WooCommerce single product data tabs programatically

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written a piece of code that add's the single product tab's name to the url, when you click on a specific product tab. For example, when you click on the tab 'Additional Information', the url in the browser will be appended with '#additional_information'.

My goal now is that when you enter that url directly ("mySite/productName#additional_information"), the single product is loaded and the corresponding data tab will be activated and visible.

Although this should be straight forward jQuery (removing and adding 'active' class to the tabs and hiding and showing the corresponding data panels), this is not working. It seems like my code is being executed properly, but then ultimately the code is being overwritten.

See this page for an example: https://ecco-dev.be/be/producten/drainbase-kunstgrasplaten/#general_info

So what am I overlooking here?

My code:

```
function changeProductUrlsByDataTabsValue() {
        let baseUrl = window.location.href;
        let index, suffix, target, newUrl, targetTabClass, targetPanelClass;

        // Activate the corresponding data tab on page load
        if (baseUrl.indexOf("#") >= 0) {
            index = baseUrl.indexOf("#");
            suffix = baseUrl.substring(index + 1);
            targetTabClass = '.' + suffix + '_tab';
            targetPanelClass = '.woocommerce-Tabs-panel--' + suffix;
            baseUrl = baseUrl.substring(0, index - 1); 

            // Change the active data tab
            $(".woocommerce-tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(".woocommerce-Tabs-panel").hide();

            $(targetTabClass).addClass('active');
            $(targetPanelClass).show();

        } else {
            index = baseUrl.length;
            baseUrl = baseUrl.substring(0, index);
        }

        // Add the tab title to the url on click
        $('.woocommerce-tabs .tabs li a').on('click', function () {
            target = $(this).parent().attr('aria-controls');
            suffix = target.replace('tab-', '');
            newUrl = baseUrl + '#' + suffix;

            window.history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your example page is password protected, and I do not see the password anywhere.

Comment: FYI: Most of that fiddling with indexOf and subString you are doing there is pretty superfluous - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash exists.

Comment: Right, the password the see the page is Ecco987